# dotnetnuke: links to external files not working

Tags: dotnetnuke

We currently are running DotNetNuke 4.0.6. On the portals there are links that we have created to access files located on fileshares. When we set them up and save the page, then when we click that link nothing happens.

I have currently set the link up like this:
Link Type - URL
Protocol - Other
URL - file://///myfileshare/filesharename/folder1/folder2/myitem.pdf

If I select anything else (http, https, ftp) it doesn't work. When I mouse over the link it looks to be rendering correctly.

Can anyone help with why this may be happening? Am I missing a setting or selecting the wrong item?

The text in the editor is this:

Service Station for 
Please remember the information presented in the newsletter is confidential and should not be shared outside the company.
Read more... (where "Read More" is the link)

Comment: please mention some of your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few items that you want to remember here.

1. Users need to have access to that share, so it is possible that could be your issue
2. It looks like you have a few extra //'s in your link.  Should be file://, might need to switch to HTML view in the editor to modify.